# Test PendingIntent send without sleep

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-pendingintent

I got the following test case:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("test");
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction("test");
testReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    recieved=true;
  }
};
getContext().registerReceiver(testReceiver,intentFilter );
pendingIntent.send();
Thread.sleep(100);

assertTrue(recieved);
```

Is there a way to make this test pass without the Thread.sleep ?

Comment: Could you thread the code to register the receiver? You could then wait until the other thread has set the receiver up before sending the pending intent. This is probably more complicated than your solution with Thread.sleep though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CountDownLatch to wait on something like that to occur.  You initialize it with a count.  The await() methods will wait on the count to hit 0.  When it does they stop blocking (or if you specify a timeout it will return false if it timed out before the count reached 0).

Here's your sample code modified to use a CountDownLatch:

```
CountIntent intent = new Intent("test");
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction("test");

final CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
testReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    countDownLatch.countDown();
  }
};
getContext().registerReceiver(testReceiver,intentFilter );
pendingIntent.send();

assertTrue(countDownLatch.await(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
```